# how can I unique the value in foreach php?

Tags: php, wordpress

how can I unique the value here? its echo the same value more than one time!

```
foreach ( $products as $_product ) {

  foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $_product->get_id(), 'pa_color' ) as $attribute_value ){?>

    <input type="checkbox" /><?php echo esc_attr($attribute_value->name);

  }

}
```

here is the result:
[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuflK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uniques = array ();

foreach ( $products as $_product ) {
  foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $_product->get_id(), 'pa_color' ) as $attribute_value ){
    if (in_array ($attribute_value->name), $uniques) {
       continue;
    }

    $uniques[] = $attribute_value->name;
?>
    <input type="checkbox" /><?php echo esc_attr($attribute_value->name);
  }
}
```

If you need to get unique names for each product ID, make a two-dimention array.